# Regions in VS 2015 are by default open

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a lot of regions in my code. When I open a file in VS2013 - the regions are by default collapsed - which is great.

In vs2015 - when I open the same files - the regions are open.(bad)

Is there a way to configure it?

Comment: Big changes in VS2015, the hidden .suo file that keeps track of the solution state was drastically re-organized.  It is now stored in a hidden sub-directory, the file format probably changed heavily as well.  In other words, your project is going to open without VS remembering what regions were collapsed before.  Just collapse them all whenever you open a source file that you haven't opened before, it is going to remember it again.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for getting back - but it's no good for me.  I have thousends of files with regions in them - and in every version of VS till the last - they were all collapsed.

I'm working on code that has regions in it to make it more readable - now that they are open - it is less readable, and collapsing them manually is too much work to worth it.

Comment: I'm just explaining what happened.  If you want to complain at somebody then you'll have to call Microsoft.

Comment: @Noam Regions were invented for the (one and only) purpose of hiding designer generated code back in the days of Visual Studio 2002/2003 when no separation of custom- and designer- code did exist... this question might be of your interest: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio 2015 update one solved the problem - YEAH :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried collapsing to definition? `Ctrl+K , Ctrl+O`

Answer (score -1):

I think `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O` should do the trick!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10522498)

Comment: Ok - shall I remove my answer? It may mislead someone else then?